# asp.net mvc url action in javascript code and IIS publish

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing asp.net mvc project. I have a javascript object that sends query to controller action. in cshtml file I can use `@Url.Action("get", "product")` so when I publish the web site, url action is rendering by location url. If I publish it `http://localhost/App1/`, the action url is like this `http://localhost/App1/product/get` or I can publish it another directory like `http://localhost/App2/` and so on.

But I have an issue in javascript code.

**sample.js**

```
function query(){
    var url = "/product/get";

    // send query this url
}
```

When I publish the project in `http://localhost/App1/` url (APP1 folder), javascript query is sending request to `http://localhost/product/get` , but it should be like this `http://localhost/App1/product/get`

I can not use `@Url.action()` razor expression. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: How are you using `query()`?

Comment: Why can not you use @Url.action() razor expression if it is mvc 4 application?

Answer (score 1):

You can place root level `appPath` variable in your `_layout.cshtml`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var appPath = @Url.Content("~/");
</script>
```

Then in your query

```
function query(){
    var url = appPath +"/product/get";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I send the url as a parameter from the View to the javascript function which is written in a js file. This saves you the trouble of creating a url in js and you can use you razor expression for the same.

So your function becomes:-

```
function query(url){
//var url = "/product/get";
// send query this url
}
```